# Manage Sign with Apple redirect in PHP

Tags: php, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to implement Sign In with Apple workflow on a backend server, for all those devices that do not support it natively.

I've tried both with and without 3rd party libraries. Right now I'm using [`patrickbussmann/oauth2-apple`](https://packagist.org/packages/patrickbussmann/oauth2-apple).

I successfully authorize the account through the authorization URL, but the redirect URL have no fields (especially the 'code' one).
This is how I generate the authorization URL:

```
function get_apple_signin_url() {
    $options = [
        'scope' => ['email'],
    ];
    $authUrl = $this->provider->getAuthorizationUrl($options);
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $this->provider->getState();
    return '{"url": "'.$authUrl.'"}';
}
```

The URL obtained is correct and it works utill the end of login:
`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?scope=email&state=a9583c14408af68ac05cbfed3a8274ef&response_type=code&approval_prompt=auto&redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&response_mode=form_post`

This is the code inside the redirect uri (`apple_auth_redirect.php`):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
    $code = urlencode($_POST['code']);
    header("Location: intent://callback?apple_id_token=".$code);
} else {
    echo "no_code";
}
```

As you can see from the authorization URL, the `response_mode` is `form_post`. If I use `query` as `response_mode` I obtain the code, but I cannot insert `email` as scope. More details in `response_mode` at [Incorporating Sign in with Apple into Other Platforms (developer.apple.com)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms).

This is the current authorization workflow I've implemented:

1. Mobile app calls `get_apple_signin_url` on the server.
2. Mobile app opens the url in the browser.
3. The authorization through Apple website is completed and the browser is redirected to redirect uri `apple_auth_redirect.php`.
4. The code should be parsed by `apple_auth_redirect.php` but the redirect request has no fields.

I've implemented the same procedure for Google and Huawei sign in without problems.

Comment: Can you please reference a compatibility matrix between response modes and scopes? Also please provide a reference with that library that it should work the way you use it.

Comment: In "response_mode": the type of response mode expected. Valid values are query, fragment, and form_post. If you requested any scopes, the value must be form_post.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/incorporating_sign_in_with_apple_into_other_platforms

Comment: Thanks, hmm. It's perhaps not the issue, but `return '{"url": "'.$authUrl.'"}';` I'd do with `json_encode(['url' => $authUrl)` if the intend is to return json. Just FYI.

Comment: Ok, I will correct the json return with this code. Anyway, the mobile app successfully parse the json in the other way too.

Comment: It must not be that without json_encode the JSON is wrong, it's just that with json_encode() you have it properly handled as JSON and don't need to care. It's more a stability thing. If I want JSON I use json_encode() and then don't have to think about it. It's often also better readable than string concatenation. More these kind of things. Likely not the issue you face here, just a detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I thought that I wasn't correctly handling the redirect. However, the problem was that I wrote `redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI` without "www", just the domain e.g., "my_domain.com". With "www" e.g., "www.my_domain.com", it worked.